# UPDATE doesn't affect some rows

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is to update data in one table, using data from other table. My SELECT query fetches all needed rows, but UPDATE query affects nothing. What is wrong?
Here is SELECT query:

```
SELECT 
t1.id,
COUNT(*) 
FROM table_1 as t1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 as t2 
    ON t1.system_id =  t2.system_id 
    AND t1.tenant_id = t2.tenant_id 
    AND name LIKE '%<ohne>' 
    AND t2.created_by_id = '1'  
    WHERE t1.system_project_id IS NULL
```

Here is UDATE query

```
UPDATE table_1 as t1  
LEFT JOIN table_2 as t2 
ON t1.system_id =  t2.system_id 
   AND t1.tenant_id = t2.tenant_id 
   AND name LIKE '%<ohne>' 
   AND t2.created_by_id = '1' 
   SET t1.system_project_id = t2.id 
   WHERE t1.system_project_id IS NULL
```

Table stucture:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tenant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `system_id` int(11) NOT NULL,      
  `system_project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `system_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Sample data:

```
table_1: 
 id: 1
 tenant_id:1
 system_id:1
 system_project_id:NULL

table2:
 id:1
 tenant_id:1
 system_id:1
 name:blabla<ohne>
 created_by_id:1
```

Expected data after UPDATE:

```
 table_1: 
  id: 1
  tenant_id:1
  system_id:1
  system_project_id:1
```

I've slightly updated my query, so how it now looks like:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT t2.id FROM table_1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 as t2 ON t1.system_id =  t2.system_id 
AND t1.tenant_id = t2.tenant_id AND name LIKE '%<ohne>' AND syp.created_by_id = '1' 
WHERE t1.system_project_id IS NULL 
) 
THEN 
    UPDATE table_1 as t1_1
    SET t1.system_project_id =  t2.id 
    FROM table_2 as syp WHERE t1_1.system_id =  t2.system_id 
    AND t1_1.tenant_id = t2.tenant_id AND name LIKE '%<ohne>' AND t2.created_by_id = '1' 
    AND t1_1.system_project_id IS NULL;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO table_2 (created_by_id, updated_by_id, system_id, created_at, updated_at,             name, tenant_id)
    SELECT 1,1, t1_1.system_id, NOW(), NOW(), CONCAT(t3.name,'<ohne>'), t1_1.tenant_id
    FROM table_1 as t1_1
    LEFT JOIN table_3 as t3 ON rem.system_id = t3.id
    WHERE t1_1.system_project_id IS NULL;
END IF;
```

Dut it still doesn't work.
table_3 is only a connection table for getting 'name'.

Comment: Presumably, `t2.id` is always `NULL` when `t1.system_project_id IS NULL`.

Comment: Selecting t1.id but setting t2.id in update? Can you select t2.id, see the count

Comment: yes, selecting t2.id with that SELECT query returns NULL - so, thats a task, to complete all t1 rows with missing system_project_id.

Comment: How do you want to UPDATE t1 if you don't have matching data in t2? Please provide sample date plus expected contents of t1 after the UPDATE.

Comment: @Kamil Just edit your question to include additional information like this and then comment that you have edited.  Comments can't really hold sql code, and anyone who sees your question later needs to see all the information in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this select statement.

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.id, t1.system_project_id FROM table2 AS t2, table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 as t2 ON   t2.id = t1.system_project_id
WHERE t1.tenant_id = t2.tenant_id 
AND t1.system_id =  t2.system_id
AND name LIKE '%<ohne>' AND t2.created_by_id = '1' 
AND t1.system_project_id IS NULL`enter code here`
```

The left join on table_2 can create t1.id nulls in your results table. These are rows in table_2 where the corresponding table_1 row is missing.

You should not be using "AND name LIKE '%' " as a ON clause.

where t1.id IS NOT NULL, update
Where t1.id IS NULL, insert